# Output function with loop input, HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a website using HTML for my final in my class and I am having some issues getting my text form to generate an output. I wanted to do the console.log output from the loop but I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong. I only have numbers 0-2 in the loop so far because I wanted to test it before I could get it to work. Any help is appreciated, thank you! [enter image description here][1]

```html
<form action="years.php">
  <label for="year">I want to go back __ years.</label>
  <input type="text" id="year" name="year">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</body>

<p id="year"></p>

<script
var year = new Array();
year[0] = "This was an eventful year"
year[1] = "Scientists release first-ever image of black hole";
year[2] = "The United States Leaves the Iran Nuclear Deal";

var index=0;

for (index; index < year.length; ++index) 
</script>
<form>
  <console class="year"></console>
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete, the for loop doesn’t do anything right now. Also your script tag has a mismatched `>`

Comment: Try : `for (index; index < year.length; ++index) {console.log(year[index])}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply `console.log()` the items in `year` then complete the for loop like such:

```js
for (index; index < year.length; ++index) console.log(year[index])
```

If you want to add the items to the `<p>` tag in your HTML then add this to your script in place of the for loop:

```js
let str = ""
let p = document.querySelector('p#year')
for (index; index < year.length; ++index) {
    str += year[index] + '<br>'
}
p.innerHTML += str
```

Answer (score 0):

I reorganized your code as I understand it. What I understand is you want to get a year input from the user. If the input is **2**, that means you want to display **what happened 2 years ago**.

**HTML:**

```
<form action="years.php" id="my-form">
  <label for="year">I want to go back __ years.</label>
  <input type="number" id="year" name="year">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

<h3>What happened "x" years ago</h3>
<p id="event-output"></p>

<h3>What happened from "x" years ago until today</h3>
<p id="events-output"></p>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
/* DOM Elements */
const myForm = document.getElementById("my-form");
const eventOutput = document.getElementById("event-output");
const eventsOutput = document.getElementById("events-output");
const yearInput = document.getElementById("year");

/* Variables */
const events = [
    "This was an eventful year",
    "Scientists release first-ever image of black hole",
    "The United States Leaves the Iran Nuclear Deal"
];

let index;

/* Event Listeners */
myForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // Get the year input value
    const index = +yearInput.value;
    
    // Display the corresponding event
    eventOutput.innerHTML = events[index];
    
    // Display events since that year
    let output = "";
    
    for(let i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
        output += events[i] + "<br>";
    }
    
    eventsOutput.innerHTML = output;
});
```

**So here is what I did:**

- Changed some of your "id"s and variable names to make them more meaningful.
- You used id = year twice, so I fixed that.
- In script, I got the form element and added a "submit" event to it. So when the form is submitted (when submit button is clicked), I prevented the default action(refreshing the page) with e.preventDefault(). I got the year input value that user entered ("+" at the beginning just parses string to an integer). Finally, displayed the event that happened "x" years ago, and displayed all events that happened from "x" years ago until today by using a for loop and adding the event to a "output" variable.

Here you can test it out: https://jsfiddle.net/ch09vop1/